# Rundeck; Need to change the IP

Tags: rundeck

I am relativity new to running run deck and i have been stuck on the same issue for the last two days. I am trying to do the simple task of changing the IP address from a local host address to another ip. I have already altered framework.server.name, .hostname, .port, .serverurl. I also changed the rund-deck-configs.properties grails.serverURL to my ip address. i have tried different ips. While i have changed all o9f those (after rebooting ubuntu) i get an error when starting rundeck that something is using port 4440, but i have already moved everything to port 22950.

EDIT: The issue had nothing to do with rundeck but my lack of understanding with the server ip section. To fix the issue all i did was assign the address of my computer to the amended files and it worked. Hope this helps anyone else with the same issues

Comment: ubuntu 20.10, turned off firewall, and am on rundeck 3.3.2-20200817

Comment: Can you share the error that are you seeing? you can get it from service.log file, usually at /var/log/rundeck path (please hide or change any potentially sensitive information). Also, what kind of installation are you using DEB based or WAR based? Greetings!

Comment: sorry for being vague as is yes i can add. Current error is webserver failed to start. Port 4400 was already in use. But i have changed that port to 22950 on all the server files.

Comment: The other error was the no connect error. and this is being used through .war.

Comment: interesting enough, rebooted the system and now am getting a new error. The error is:                                                                                                                                                              Failed to bind properties under 'server.address' to java.net.InetAddress:

    Property: server.address
    Value: 10.7.5.60:22950
    Origin: "server.address" from property source "rundeck.config.location"
    Reason: failed to convert java.lang.String to java.net.InetAddress

Answer (score 1):

For WAR based installation follow these steps.

1. Check the [system requirements](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/install/system-requirements.html#system-requirements), in your case, focus on your JDK version (3.3.X branch works with JDK 8 and JDK 11), then [download](https://packagecloud.io/pagerduty/rundeck/packages/java/org.rundeck/rundeck-3.3.2-20200727.war/artifacts/rundeck-3.3.2-20200727.war/download) Rundeck WAR file and save it in some directory.
2. Launch Rundeck for the first time to generate all files, for that do: `java -jar rundeck-3.3.2-20200817.war`, after that stop it with `ctrl+c`.
3. Change the `grails.serverURL` parameter on `rundeck-config.properties`  file (at `/your/rundeck/path/server/config` path) with your custom port, for example, `grails.serverURL=http://your-ip:5555`. Also, set `server.address` to `0.0.0.0` to listen conections from outside: `server.address=0.0.0.0`.
4. Change the `framework.server.port` and `framework.server.url` on your `framework.properties` file accodingly to your custom port (at `/your/rundeck/path/etc` path), on my example `framework.server.port = 5555` and `framework.server.url = http://your-ip:5555`
5. Now launch Rundeck with: `java -jar -Dserver.http.port=5555 rundeck-3.3.2-20200817.war`

Now, you can [see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMKte.jpg) Rundeck running on a custom port (5555 in my example).

Comment: Is this local? Im trying to get it to be availible to all systems on the network and can still only access it only from the local computer.

Comment: Check the step 3, with server.address=0.0.0.0 on rundeck-config.properties the instance is reachable by any external computer on your network.

Comment: Weird. i can ping it yet still no gui.

Comment: Check any firewall/network issue, also, check the steps 3 and 4 carefully (step 3 is on rundeck-config.properties and step 4 is on framework.properties). Just in case, restart your instance after any config file changes.

Comment: I cant thank you enough. It ended up being a very simple issue with step 3 and 4 where i was entering a new ip address instead of the one my computer was currently running. Thank you for thelp

Comment: Good news then, any time :-)