# Can we have two instances of Rundeck installed on same server?

Tags: installation, upgrade, rundeck

I have rundeck 3.3.10 installed on my RedHat server , I want to upgrade to 4.0.1 community version.But I want to keep the older version intact, while I install and setup the latest version. Is it possible ,if yes what are the steps to achieve this ?
I checked on PagerDuty site but couldnt find the information i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep two instances in this way:

The first one installed from the RPM/repo listening to the port 4440 and the second one could be installed as a WAR (for example, in the `/opt/rundeck` directory) and listening to another port, e.g: 4441.

You can see [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63713238/10426011) how to configure the second instance.

But if you're looking to keep two RPM instances, the best way is to replicate the 4.0.1 upgrade in a virtual machine (like Vagrant) and later upgrade your main server.

NOTE: Don't connect both instances against the same database, I assume that you're creating a specific database for the 2nd instance.

Comment: Thanks for your response . Can you also share the steps to create new DB specific to a instance ? I am trying to edit existing DB config as per steps mentioned here . https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/install/installing-rundeck.html#database-configuration

Comment: Take a look at this: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/database/#database-overview

Comment: Thanks so much it was really helpful . After following all the steps and making config changes I am able to see the new rundeck service running on Linux server ,but its still not accessible via UI .Any idea ? The page shows "the site can't be reached "

Comment: Check the grails.serverURL parameter at rundeck-config.properties file carefully, take a look: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/1935#issuecomment-231126563 Also, discard any firewall/network config OS issue.